# Check values from array not workig as expected

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I have this method:

```
void isInteger() {
    int nums[] = new int[6];
    try {
        nums[0] = Integer.parseInt(jFormattedTextField1.getText());
        nums[1] = Integer.parseInt(jFormattedTextField2.getText());
        nums[2] = Integer.parseInt(jFormattedTextField3.getText());
        nums[3] = Integer.parseInt(jFormattedTextField4.getText());
        nums[4] = Integer.parseInt(jFormattedTextField5.getText());
        nums[5] = Integer.parseInt(jFormattedTextField6.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid format or no input error" + e);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        if (nums[i] == nums[i + 1]) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Repeated number error");
            return;
        }
        if (nums[i] < 1 || nums[i] > 48) {
            //out of number range tell user of error
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Range error");
            return;
        }
    }


}
```

First 5 numbers are working and if I type number higher than 48 in any of textfields except jFormattedTextField6 it gives me exception as it should.

I guess there is something wrong with `for(int i=0; i<5; i++)` but i can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating the for loop for 5 times as below :

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)  //Size of array is 6 but iterating only 5 times
```

When you enter value more than 48 in any of 5 text field then

```
if (nums[i] < 1 || nums[i] > 48)
```

this statement becomes true and you will receive message as **Range error** in message dialog.As you are using return then there will not be any further execution of loop.

Comment: But the `for` loop is <5, not <= 5

Comment: @user3421018 I have updated.Also which exception you receive when enter number > 48 ??

Comment: I have not personally ran the code. I just noticed the for loop

Comment: I miss understood,though u asked the question @MikeKoch

Answer (score 1):

Your loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

is correct because you are using `nums[i + 1]`. But you will have to handle the last case separately:

```
int len = nums.length();

// This will loop in the range [0, len-2], in other words
// from the first index to the one before the last
for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    // ...
}

// Handle the last element of array
if (nums[len-1] < 1 || nums[len-1] > 48) {
    // ...
}
```

**Note:** I would recommend you to set a variable (in the example above `len`) to be the length of the array, so you don't have to set it manually each time you want to modify it. You have to avoid *magic numbers*.